# Best Java Frameworks for learning

Tags: java, frameworks

What would be a good Java framework to explore for someone looking to learn?  I've played around with the Android api but had someone ask what other frameworks I had experience with so I thought I should spend some time working with another.  What's the best bang for my time?

Comment: That really depends on what you're trying to get out of it. More Java experience? A better CV? Are you purely looking to lean mobile APIs?

Comment: Completely open-ended, subjective, unanswerable question. Web apps? Desktop? Mobile? General purpose? Targeted? What do you want to write? How do you want to write it?

Comment: Not sure this is really an appropriate question, given the FAQ. (You're relying on opinion here) What is wrong with plain old Java?

Comment: Basically learning a framework would help him manage many layers of his application in an easier way as well as shorten the development cycle and be more efficient.

Comment: @gaspyr Totally depends on what kind(s) of apps and other factors. Without any context, making blanket statements about what would and wouldn't help is guessing.

Comment: @gaspyr Learning a framework does indeed help with managing his application and shorten the dev cycle, however, if he's looking to learn for the sake of educating himself better in the programming language, he should probably start off with the standard libraries and work his way from the ground up. Though if he already is well versed in Java, then learning new technologies would definitely be the next step for him

Comment: i agree with everything that has been said :), and regarding topic i simply answered to the web context of the question as the asker wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many java frameworks but we can categorize two parts.

Standard Frameworks

- JSF
- JSP & Servlets
- JPA
- EJB

Non Standard Frameworks

- Spring
- Strut
- Wicket
- GWT
- Hibernate
- Seam
- Play
- Others

Answer (score 1):

For web frameworks i suggest : Spring, Hibernate, Struts, Primefaces (cool stuff) .

Comment: With the caveats that Spring is huge and you should pick what part(s) of Spring you want to learn, and "Struts" can mean either Struts 1 (don't bother unless you're hell-bent on writing code like it's a decade ago or really want to be a maintenance dev) or Struts 2 (comparable to Spring MVC).

Comment: I didn't want to specify the versions as the question only asked about the framework's names. Concerning the learning curve, yes it requires a real investment, but very much worth it, after all passion for code is what moves a programmer's life :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what it is you're trying to gain experience with. If you are looking for web frameworks, gaspyr named some decent ones you should try (I've worked with Spring myself). If you are looking to develop just desktop applications or embedded solutions, I would just go with tackling the standard JRE, and take special note on how the differences between how applications, applets, and servlets run. It's always good to know about the underlying libraries themselves rather than just understanding the syntax and attempting to use a framework to solve all problems without understanding how they might work under the hood.

But this is a really open ended question, and it's difficult to know exactly what you're looking for and why.

Answer (score 0):

Framework choice depends on many factors and good documentation is not the least.

There is incredible book ["Spring in Action"](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) if you will decide to start with Spring.